# Question about AuthorizeNet ARB functionality with UC Recurring Module

Tags: 6, ubercart, payment-gateways

I am confused about how the AuthorizeNet ARB functionality is supposed to work in Ubercart 2, and am hopeful that someone here has experience with AuthNet ARB recurring orders. I have the [UC Recurring Payments and Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) module and my AuthNet gateway set up. I created a recurring test order, and the recurring information is being displayed properly in my AuthorizeNet account. Last night, the first recurring charge took place, and I see that charge in my AuthorizeNet account, but it did not create any new order or any other message within my Ubercart account. The Recurring Fees screen for the order in question still shows that it has all of its recurring charges remaining. I ran cron, but that did not update anything.

The only thing I did not do in my AuthorizeNet gateway setup in Ubercart is the "Log reported ARB payments in watchdog." setting... I do not have that setting enabled, and I did not add the url to the Silent POST URL setting in AuthorizeNet. Is that what I'm missing? Or does it sound like there is something else missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enabled the "Log reported ARB payments in watchdog" setting and added the url to the Silent POST URL setting in AuthorizeNet. It is now working fine and recording the recurring transactions in my Ubercart Orders screen.